# Posting messages from a service worker to a client page

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Today we can find many examples of sending message from a service worker to a client, but always following the reception of a `message` event in the service worker.

I would like to know if we can send messages independently of this event? And if yes, how? I tried few things, without success...

In my case, it's for redirect a client to a new page when my service worker receives a `push` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface for [`Client.postMessage()`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#client-postmessage) is described at https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/609. Unfortunately, it is not fully implemented in Google Chrome as of version 45, though I'd expect it to make it into a version at a later date.

When the functionality's available, you could use [`self.clients.matchAll()`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#clients-matchall-method) to obtain a list of any open pages that are being controlled by the service worker, and call the `postMessage()` method on the specific client that you care about. You need to keep in mind that it's entirely possible that there won't be any tabs open with a page controlled by your service worker, in which case you'd want to do something like open a new client page with your target URL.

**But**, there's a method that's probably more appropriate for your use case (though also not currently support in Chrome 45): [`WindowClient.navigate()`](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#client-navigate), which will instruct an open tab controlled by your service worker to navigate to a different URL on the same origin.

Answer (score 9):

client.js :

```
const swListener = new BroadcastChannel('swListener');
swListener.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('swListener Received', e.data);
};
```

service-worker.js

```
  const swListener = new BroadcastChannel('swListener');
   swListener.postMessage('This is From SW');
```